# how to avoid design break up in html

Tags: html, css

This is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  padding: none;
  background: green;
}
.layoutTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bodyStyle,
html,
.layoutTable {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="layoutTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- japaneseclass Schedule -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The output:

[image: Output]

I ran this code in IE11 and there is a gap between body and table, I don't know how to remove this, and the design breaks on zoom.

Answer (score 2):

**All HTML document by default have a margin surrounding all four corners of it. As desirable as margins are in most cases, sometimes they with your design, such as a header bar that spans the entire page horizontally. In this tutorial I'll show you the two techniques most commonly used to remove the document's margins, so content presses right against the edge of the window.**

```
 <body bgcolor="green" style="padding:0;margin:0">
```

Comment: You can also set with css like body{margin:0,padding:0}

Answer (score 1):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/avVQQy?editors=110

This seems to remove the gap between your elements all you need to do was add `padding:0;` & `margin:0;` to the `body` tag i'm not sure what you mean when you say the design breaks whenever you zoom though can you explain?

Also it seems redundant to have a separate class for `body` ie `bodystyle`(assuming thats what your using that for) when you can just use `body` as a selector itself

Comment: i ran the code in ie11, And the design breaks(collapse) when we implement the table., that is if we put one textbox within <td>tag, the size of textbox is overflow than <td> size when it is zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot to attach your `bodyStyle` class in your CSS to the `body` tag in your HTML...

`<body bgcolor="green" style="padding:none;" class="bodyStyle">`

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to do a 'browser reset' as all browsers treat this gap differently. That's why you should add the following css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```